# php Warning date() invalid date.timezone value,, we selected UTC timezone for now on server

Tags: php

**Warning**: date(): Invalid date.timezone value 'Asia/Singapore', we selected the timezone 'UTC' for now: in **path/file.php** on line 14.

i'm having above error when running on the server, while in my code i did not put any timezone.

well the things is, if im running on my local wamp server, there's no error display at all.

below is my code
[image]

please advice.
thanks.

Comment: How have you set the timezone? Can we see that.

Comment: Your also mixing mysqli_* procedural based and oop style mysqli, which won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add following line before use of date function.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');//change zone as per need
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Singapore"
```

Edit:

Let's locate the correct php.ini. Fire this within apache / nginx / whatever web server deamon your using (because the command line version may be different by the one used by it).

```
<?php
 phpinfo();
?>
```

What's the .ini in the output? Still the same?

Edit2:

After the php.ini edit, just restart the webserver (apache or nginx.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to ignore the warning, you can put this code at your first line

> error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING)

**about timezone setting**:
not only PHP page can be set timezone but also php.ini can be set it.